# JPA: join tables but after that still makes sequence of queries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, join

I'm sorry if that is too silly or not complete.
I want to make one query, joining all tables at once.

```
@NamedQuery(name="User.findByLogin",
        query="SELECT u FROM User u " +
          "left outer join fetch u.userInfo ui " +
              "left outer join fetch u.freeEvents fe " +
              "left outer join fetch u.paidEvents pe " +
              "left outer join fetch fe.action fea " +
              "left outer join fetch pe.action pea " +
              "where u.login = :login")
```

and it works (no errors, no warnings, sql generated), and SQL is fine, and all appropriate data is retrieved in mysql console. But after that it makes many requests to find actions by id, and it looks like hibernate doesn't know that it had already fetched all needed data or have no idea what to do with it.
All other similar joins with two tables are valid and work as expected.
By the way, freeEvent and paidEvent are @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE), they differs by "rate_type" column. I tried both eager and lazy fetch, and hibernate @Fetch annotation.
The sql itself:

```
select * #---lots of fields here, all valid
  from Users user0_ left outer join UserInfos userinfo1_ on user0_.`user_info_id`=userinfo1_.id
            left outer join Events freeevents2_ on user0_.id=freeevents2_.`user_id` and freeevents2_.rate_type=1
            left outer join FreeActions freeaction4_ on freeevents2_.`action_id`=freeaction4_.`id`
            left outer join Events paidevents3_ on user0_.id=paidevents3_.`user_id` and paidevents3_.rate_type=2
            left outer join PaidActions paidaction5_ on paidevents3_.`action_id`=paidaction5_.`id` where user0_.`login`='testuser'
```

Question: where is the problem? Are my classes poorly annotated, or that is a normal hibernate behaviour, where to find a solution?

Entities: (without getters, setters and fields that are not mapped by anyone)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Events")
@PersistenceUnit(name="default")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="rate_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class AbstractEvent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private models.User user;

    @Column(name="rate_type", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private byte rateType;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(RateTypeHelper.RATE_TYPE_FREE) //it just a constant of type integer == 1
@PersistenceUnit(name="default")
public class FreeEvent extends models.events.AbstractEvent {

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="`action_id`")
    private FreeAction action;

    public FreeAction getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(FreeAction action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(RateTypeHelper.RATE_TYPE_PAID)
@PersistenceUnit(name="default")
public class PaidEvent extends models.events.AbstractEvent {

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="`action_id`")
    private PaidAction action;

    public PaidAction getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(PaidAction action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
}
```

Note: abstract action here is not used now. It doesn't have any fields or methods. Just empty class for futures needs.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FreeActions")
@PersistenceUnit(name="default")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="FreeAction.findByUserId",
                query="select a from FreeAction a " +
                      "left outer join fetch a.event e " +
                      "where e.user = :user_id")
})
public class FreeAction extends AbstractAction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="`id`")
    private Long Id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="action", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private models.events.FreeEvent event;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PaidActions")
@PersistenceUnit(name="default")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="PaidAction.findByUserId",
                query="select a from PaidAction a " +
                      "left outer join fetch a.event e " +
                      "where e.user = :user_id")
})

public class PaidAction extends AbstractAction {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="`id`")
    private Long Id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="action", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private models.events.PaidEvent event;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
@PersistenceUnit(name="default")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="findFullUserById",
                query="select u from User u "+ 
                      "left outer join fetch u.userInfo ui " +
                      "where u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findByLoginPassword",
                query="SELECT u FROM User u left outer join fetch u.userInfo ui " +
                      "where u.login = :login and u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findByLogin",
                query="SELECT u FROM User u " +
                      "left outer join fetch u.userInfo ui " +
                      "left outer join fetch u.freeEvents fe " +
                      "left outer join fetch u.paidEvents pe " +
                      "left outer join fetch fe.action fea " +
                      "left outer join fetch pe.action pea " +
                      "where u.login = :login")
})
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long Id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="`user_id`")
    private Set<FreeEvent> freeEvents;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="`user_id`")
    private Set<PaidEvent> paidEvents;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="`user_info_id`")
    private UserInfo userInfo;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="UserInfos")
@PersistenceUnit(name="default")
public class UserInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long Id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="userInfo")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: Can u post your entities

Comment: Is it just the action references that aren't fetched?  JPA/JPQL does not support nested join fetches, so it could be that Hibernate is just ignoring the Fetch portion of the fe.action fea and  pe.action pea joins rather than throwing a validation type exception.  Other providers have ways to support nested fetching other than changing the mappings, such as query hints - Hibernate might have similar non-JPA methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why are u using left outer join? JPA understands that the set being a member of User will use the join to fetch them, albeit lazily when needed?

Now to the fact that you see more requests may be to the fact that you have FetchType.LAZY, and at the point you invoke one of getFreeEvents(), getPaidEvents(), getUserInfo(), hibernate will fire another sql query requests to retrieve them, as at this point they are not yet loaded.

Comment: I use left outer join, cuz I want to retrieve two tabled with different columns in one request.
I used both LAZY and EAGER, I know about it. Also, when fetch join is used it always EAGER and sometimes I want to get one part of class, for example, just User without UserInfo just to check that user exists in databes.

Comment: Those entities are already part of User. If you want to retrieve the values at the point of getting the User, then use EAGER. It beats logic that you have LAZY, and then use namedquery to load the set eagerly

Comment: It uses sequence of selects even for simple fetch join with EAGER, when I join child of AbstractEvent with any other class. When I join User with UserInfo the same way, using fetch join (no matter inner, outer. left, right) it makes only one query, but when I use FreeEvent and join it with something, it first prepare one big SQL with all data, and then again many requests.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.
For example, I have 2 classes - User and Role. When I create Entities like that

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
@PersistenceUnit(name="default")
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "USERS_SEQ", sequenceName = "USERS_SEQ")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findByLoginPassword",
                query="SELECT u FROM User u left outer join fetch u.role r " +
                      "where u.login = :login and u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findByLogin",
                query="SELECT u FROM User u left outer join fetch u.role r " +
                      "WHERE u.login = :login"),
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findAll",
                query="SELECT u FROM User u left outer join fetch u.role r"),
    @NamedQuery(name="User.findByRoleId",
                query="SELECT u FROM User u left outer join fetch u.role r " +
                      "where r.id = :role_id")
}) 
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USERS_SEQ")
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long Id;
    @Required
    private String login;
    @Required
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @Required
    private Role role;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Roles")
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "ROLES_SEQ", sequenceName = "ROLES_SEQ")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Role.findEmptyRole",
                query="SELECT r FROM Role r " +
                      "where r.canRead=" + FALSE + " and r.canWrite=" + FALSE + " and r.canExecute=" + FALSE + " and r.canAdministrate=" + FALSE),
    @NamedQuery(name="Role.findAdminRole",
                query="SELECT r FROM Role r " +
                      "where r.canRead=" + TRUE + " and r.canWrite=" + TRUE + " and r.canExecute=" + TRUE + " and r.canAdministrate=" + TRUE)
}) 
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ROLES_SEQ")
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="r")
    private boolean canRead;
    @Column(name="w")
    private boolean canWrite;
    @Column(name="x")
    private boolean canExecute;
    @Column(name="a")
    private boolean canAdministrate;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<User> owners;
}
```

Every time I get User, despite of EAGER or LAZY, or hibernate @Fetch, or @Required I get 2 requests. But when I don't use field

```
List<User> owners
```

in Role, then FETCH works (again, it doesn't matter weather I use LAZY or EAGER).

Same thing with my classes. I removed back links to owners,

```
//@OneToOne(mappedBy="action")
//private models.events.FreeEvent event;

//@OneToOne(mappedBy="action")
//private models.events.PaidEvent event;
```

etc. And it uses now one request to get every data by join fetch.

I'm sorry if I don't understand some mechanisms of JPA.